# Is there any possibility or option to get the query which causes postgres slave server to get short of memory

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

From the postgres logs:

```
2020-06-23 10:15:36 UTC [6052]: [1-1] db=,user= LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file 
"pg_stat_tmp/db_16387.tmp": No space left on device
 2020-06-23 10:15:36 UTC [6052]: [2-1] db=,user= LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file 
"pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device
2020-06-23 10:15:37 UTC [6039]: [8-1] db=,user= FATAL:  could not extend file 
"base/16387/1102307.196": No space left on device
2020-06-23 10:15:37 UTC [6039]: [9-1] db=,user= HINT:  Check free disk space.
2020-06-23 10:15:37 UTC [6039]: [10-1] db=,user= CONTEXT:  xlog redo insert(init): rel 1 
1663/16387/1102307; tid 25769659/1
2020-06-23 10:15:40 UTC [19987]: [11-1] db=prime,user=prime_user ERROR:  could not write block 
6537 of temporary file: No space left on device
```

Is there any possibility and postgres maintains logs about the long running query?

Comment: The problem is not a query on the replica.  Rather, there is not enough disk space to replicate what the master has sent it.

Comment: Then can a query be a reason for the no space left ,if it is running for a long time and eaten up the space ?